# Updates and installs in a cell in a Jupyternotebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a small question. I am working in a Jupyternotebook in PyCharm. Now I want to start programming something and I have now updated pip and installed mxnet. This time I did not do it through the terminal, but in a cell of the Jupyter notebook. Is it enough to run this cell once and then I can delete it or should I keep it and run it again on every restart of the notebook?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. Just make sure that you are working in the same environment as before.

Comment: Unless you documented it somewhere else, it is best to keep it in the notebook. Running the cell again doesn't cause any issues; however, forgetting what you did later can lead you to a world of complications. Also, I suggest explicitly using the modern magic commands for use with `pip` & `conda`, namely `%pip` & `%conda` when using those in cells in your notebook. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about those if you don't know about them. Anything you see using an exclamation point is outdated.

Comment: okay thank you. That is a really good point. I used to install and update everything inside the terminal with the command :' file path pip install pandas'. Pandas is only one example at this point. I saw in a video that inside a cell of a Jupyternotebook it should go like this:
!pip install pandas             Is this correct? As I said I use PyCharm, Pandas and Jupyternotebooks